# show notification after completable future succeed

Tags: java, vaadin, completable-future

I've got a method called `showNotification` that shows notification

```
public static void showNotification(UI ui, String notificationMessage) {
        Notification notification = new Notification(notificationMessage);
        notification.setStyleName("custom-notification");
        notification.show(ui.getPage());
}
```

And I've got a service that returns `CompletableFuture`. 
In my controller I created method

```
@Override
public CompletableFuture<?> startProcessing() {
    return processorService.start();
}
```

And on button click I want to show notification if `start` was successful. 
My `buttonClick` event looks like this

```
event -> {
    controller.startProcessing()
        .thenAccept(aVoid -> UI.getCurrent().access(() -> {
                showNotification(getUI(), "Started processing");
            })
        ).handle((aVoid, throwable) -> {
               showNotification(getUI(), "Failed to start processing");
            return aVoid;
        });
}
```

The problem is that until I invoke another event - like for example click on another button - it doesn't show notification.

What is the problem?

Comment: Beware that in Vaadin 7, `UI.getCurrent()` may return the wrong `UI` in many situations. In Vaadin 8, it will instead return `null` to avoid the risk of publishing sensitive information to the wrong user. This happens because `UI.getCurrent()` is based on a `ThreadLocal`, but e.g. the `thenAccept` callback might actually be run on a different thread.

You should instead create a `UI ui = UI.getCurrent();` variable directly in the click handler and reference that inside the `thenAccept` handler.

Comment: @LeifÅstrand it seems even without `UI.getCurrent` it works the same. So I probably doesn't need that at all.

Comment: You say that a notification is shown after invoking some other event. Is it `Started processing` or `Failed to start processing` that is shown?
One observation is that you'd also need to do `UI.access` inside the `handle` callback. Without that, `@Push` won't have any effect if that's where it ends up.

Comment: I'd also recommend that you add some logging to help verify which parts of the code are actually run.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `@Push` to your UI subclass to make the browser open a two-directional connection with the server. Without that, only the browser can initiate communication, and it only does that when there's some new event to send to the server.

Comment: Hm...So I only need to add this annotation and it will then show the notification as I expect it?

Comment: An alternative is [polling](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/articles/UsingPolling.html). This will make the client do requests in the specified interval.

Comment: Btw [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html) is the link to documentation of @Push.

Comment: adding `@Push` did not help. In logs it shows that everything has started, but until I click on some button I don't get any notifications

Comment: @lapots You could try to manually call `ui.push()` for testing. Do the logs say anything about push?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich manually? You mean just to add `push` in my method? Nothing about push in logs. Only my own log messages from services

Comment: @SteffenHarbich what might be the reason for additional execution of `handle`? It shows both notifications

Comment: @lapots I have no idea what prevents your automatic push. Maybe you could ask another question on SO.

Comment: Automatic Push has some internal logic for bundling push events optimally. This means, that in some corner cases the automatic push may be delayed. In these cases you need to apply manual push with ui.push(). You can do that also in automatic mode.